# Customers ordering both S and M: howto detect and counter ;)

Tags: checkout, configurable-product

we have a shop that sells T-shirts

Sometimes we have customers that buy both a S(mall) and M(edium)

captured in an attribute on simple product: shirt_size, that is aggregated in a configurable product

Almost 99% are customers that decide to buy bought, and decide later ....

This leads to many unnecessary RMA's

We would rather *warn* these customers during checkout, or in cart to call us

**My question:** How could I capture that two products of the same attribute set were ordered with different simple product identifiers (shirts_size) and if this is true - show a certain cms block in checkout (stating something like "hey, it seems you bought two different sizes. Can we help you choose the rigth size? Call us on 555-HELPME"

(I hope this is clear)

Answer (score 2):

My experience says that you're getting it all wrong.

I have several customers that sell fashion products, clothing and shoes (they all fit the bill). As it turns out when people are unsure which product fits best, they often order several sizes and return those that are either too small or too large or doesn't fit their body shape. This is part of customer behavior and and should be embraced as such. Hell, I've done that myself ...

However, while RMA-s should be part of the business model, it's still possible to reduce the number of returns. One is to implement a virtual fitter -- customer enters her measures (waist, neck, etc.) and fitter software suggests which size that fits her best. It certainly adds to overhead (you need to build the fitter and you have to measure all products one by one), so it could very well be that accepting all those RMA-s is actually cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

The question already contains the answer.

1) observe cart update event ( you need to check only product addition, no qty change or removing)

2) loop through cart items and find configurable products

3) each time remember the child item attribute value

4) if value was already remembered, add checkout session notice and stop.

What part would you like to clarify?

Comment: You build extensions, no? ;)

Comment: @snh_nl Sometimes :) see http://amasty.com . Almost any Magento modification is a module technically. Do you agree?

Comment: haha would be great to something like this - for me this is to much coding - and I am afraid it would make my store unstable

Comment: I hope someone from this site can provide a more detailed answer. I'm at the vacation now without pc, so i'm posting only general answers with almost no code )

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you could look at the events `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` and `checkout_cart_update_item_complete`. Here you can check the current cart for any items with the same parent product and add your block/message.

It might be an idea to you the session messages as I am not sure which page you will be redirected to after add/update of cart.

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addNotice('your message about the same products');
```

On a side note a customer may be ordering a large batch of t-shirts say for a group of people and this sort of message would not be needed here.